# BottomSheet is not shown at the bottom of the screen on phones with a large diagonal

Tags: flutter, dart

On a phone with a diagonal of 6.7 the bottom sheet is shown starting from the middle of the screen, although on more "normal" screens, the bottom sheet is shown starting from the bottom of the screen as it should be

[image]

*all widgets in the application are shown this way*

```
void _showRegistrationTrustInfo(BuildContext context) {
showModalBottomSheet(
    isScrollControlled: true,
    context: context,
    useSafeArea: true,
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 334 / 668,
    ),
    builder: (context) {
      return BottomSheetBody(children: [
        const Expanded(child: RegistrationForTrustInfo()),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: const Text('Закрыть')),
            )
          ],
        )
      ]);
    });
```

}

BottomSheetBody

```
  class BottomSheetBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomSheetBody({super.key, required this.children});

  final List<Widget> children;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 9),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          const TopLine(),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          ...children
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `isScrollControlled` and `useSafeArea` properties from the `showModalBottomSheet`. When you set `isScrollControlled` to true, the bottom sheet's height can be larger than the screen's height.

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  //isScrollControlled: true, //If you want the model to be full height
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
              topRight: Radius.circular(12)),
          color: Colors.red),
      child: const Center(child: Text("data")), //Your other widget placed here
    );
  },
);
```

[image]

Comment: now in the center of the screen appears

Comment: I've updated my code with a little bit describe. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this fixed size is this limiting your component height:

```
  maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 334 / 668,
```

A modal is not supposed to cover the full screen, but just a part of it, usually somewhere in the center.
Placing a modal covering the whole screen, removes the need of using that specific widget.
Instead of using a **Modal**, you can just use an **Expandable** Widget to cover the  whole screen or a **Scaffold**.